Krishna-Bhishma samvaadam during war in MahaBharatham
Just as Krishna gave Gyana to Arjuna before fighting the battle, did he also lecture at length when war was in full progress to the furious battle commander Bhishma (his senior) about his failure to act which had basically resulted in the great war?
I found the Hindi picturization and dialogues thrilling, but is it only cinematic creation or are there some authentic references in Vyasa's MahaBharatha to this exchange?
Bhishma & Krishna Verbal Encounter
Krishna provokes the talk by directly interfering and threatening to break his vow to not directly fight in the war, saying his chariot wheel is enough to destroy all Kaurava army if needed. (Telugu Video 12 min 08 sec). At the end of the long discourse at battle front Bhishma renounces weapons.

I could post a short summary if there is interest.

Krishna did not have a discussion about Gyana with Bhishma, like He did with Arjuna in the battefield.
Witnessing the conditions during the war, Lord Krishna exhibiting His divine anger charges towards Bhishma to kill him, Drona, and the whole of Kaurava army. Seeing Krishna rush towards him holding the wheel of a chariot like the Sudarshan chakra, Bhishma offers prayers to Lord Krishna and surrenders himself.
Below is an excerpt from the Mahabharata, Bhishma Parva, Chapter 55 verses 80-104.
पार्थस्य दृष्ट्वा मृदुयुद्धतां च भीष्मं च संख्ये समुदीर्यमाणम्
अमृष्यमाणः स ततो महात्मा यशस्विनं सर्वदशार्हभर्ता ।
उवाच शैनेयमभिप्रशंसन्दृष्ट्वा कुरूनापततः समन्तात् ८०-८१


Unable to bear the flight of the army, marking the mildness with which
Arjuna fights, and seeing Bhishma’s forceful exertions, and the
Kauravas rushing in from all sides, Krishna, younger brother of
Vasava, and protector of all the Dasarhas, spoke to the brave Satyaki.

ये यान्ति यान्त्वेव शिनिप्रवीर येऽपि स्थिताः सात्वत तेऽपि यान्तु ।
भीष्मं रथात्पश्य निपात्यमानं द्रोणं च संख्ये सगणं मयाद्य ८२


"O hero of Shini’s race, let they who retreat go. And let they who
remain, let them also flee. I will fling Bhishma down from his
chariot, and vanquish Drona, too, and all their followers."

नासौ रथः सात्वत कौरवाणां क्रुद्धस्य मुच्येत रणेऽद्य कश्चित् ।
तस्मादहं गृह्य रथाङ्गमुग्रं प्राणं हरिष्यामि महाव्रतस्य ॥ ८३ ॥


"No one in the Kaurava legions will escape my wrath. I will kill this
keeper of the great vow with the wheel of this fierce chariot."

निहत्य भीष्मं सगणं तथाजौ द्रोणं च शैनेय रथप्रवीरम् ।
प्रीतिं करिष्यामि धनंजयस्य राज्ञश्च भीमस्य तथाश्विनोश्च ॥ ८४ ॥


"Killing those two greatest of maharathas, Bhishma and Drona, and
their forces, O my Satyaki, I will please Arjuna and Yudhishtira, and
Bhima, and the twin Aswini-kumaras."

निहत्य सर्वान्धृतराष्ट्रपुत्रांस्तत्पक्षिणो ये च नरेन्द्रमुख्याः ।
राज्येन राजानमजातशत्रुं संपादयिष्याम्यहमद्य हृष्टः ॥ ८५ ॥


"And killing all the sons of Dhritarashtra and all their allies, I
will joyfully deliver unto the King Ajatashatru (Yudhistira) a kingdom today."

ततः सुनाभं वसुदेवपुत्रः सूर्यप्रभं वज्रसमप्रभावम् ।
क्षुरान्तमुद्यम्य भुजेन चक्रं रथादवप्लुत्य विसृज्य वाहान् ॥ ८६ ॥


The son of Vasudeva, whose navel was as bright as the sun and who was
as powerful as a thunderbolt, raising the end of the chakra with His
arm, descended from his chariot leaving behind the horses.

संकम्पयन्गां चरणैर्महात्मा वेगेन कृष्णः प्रससार भीष्मम् ।
मदान्धमाजौ समुदीर्णदर्पः सिंहो जिघांसन्निव वारणेन्द्रम् ॥ ८७ ॥


Making the earth tremble under his step, Krishna ran towards Bhishma.
He charges towards him in the midst of his forces like a lion, blinded
by intoxication and overcome with pride to kill the king of elephants.

सोऽभ्यद्रवद्भीष्ममनीकमध्ये क्रुद्धो महेन्द्रावरजः प्रमाथी ।
व्यालम्बिपीतान्तपटश्चकाशे घनो यथा खेऽचिरभापिनद्धः ॥ ८८ ॥


As the younger brother of Indra, in a fit of rage, rushed towards
Bhishma in the midst of his army, The edges of His yellow pitambara
fluttered in the air like a lightning-charged cloud in the sky.

सुदर्शनं चास्य रराज शौरेस्तच्चक्रपद्मं सुभुजोरुनालम् ।
यथादिपद्मं तरुणार्कवर्णं रराज नारायणनाभिजातम् ॥ ८९ ॥


That lotus-like Sudarsana, having for its stalk the beautiful arm of
Saurih, is as beautiful as the primeval lotus, bright as the morning
sun, which springs from the navel of Lord Narayana.

तत्कृष्णकोपोदयसूर्यबुद्धं क्षुरान्ततीक्ष्णाग्रसुजातपत्रम् ।
तस्यैव देहोरुसरःप्ररूढं रराज नारायणबाहुनालम् ॥ ९० ॥


The exquisite leaves of that lotus were as sharp as a dagger’s edge
awakened by the rising sun of Krishna's anger. Narayana's body is the
beautiful lake, and His right hand the stalk that, springing from it,
holds the shining lotus.

तमात्तचक्रं प्रणदन्तमुच्चैः क्रुद्धं महेन्द्रावरजं समीक्ष्य ।
सर्वाणि भूतानि भृशं विनेदुः क्षयं कुरूणामिति चिन्तयित्वा ॥ ९१ ॥


Seeing Him, in wrath and roaring loudly, armed with that chakra, all
creatures howled piercingly, thinking that the destruction of the
Kauravas is imminent.

स वासुदेवः प्रगृहीतचक्रः संवर्तयिष्यन्निव जीवलोकम् ।
अभ्युत्पतंल्लोकगुरुर्बभासे भूतानि धक्ष्यन्निव कालवह्निः ॥ ९२ ॥


With His chakra, Krishna looks like the Samvarta fire that appears at
the end of the yuga to consume the world. And the spiritual master of the
universe blazed like a fierce comet risen to consume all creatures.

तमापतन्तं प्रगृहीतचक्रं समीक्ष्य देवं द्विपदां वरिष्ठम् ।
असंभ्रमात्कार्मुकबाणपाणी रथे स्थितः शांतनवोऽभ्युवाच ॥ ९३ ॥


Seeing the Supreme Being advancing with the Sudarsana, Bhishma
standing in his chariot, bow and arrow in hand, cried fearlessly.

एह्येहि देवेश जगन्निवास नमोऽस्तु ते शार्ङ्गरथाङ्गपाणे ।
प्रसह्य मां पातय लोकनाथ रथोत्तमाद्भूतशरण्य संख्ये ॥ ९४ ॥


"Come, come, O Lord of the Devas, You who dwell in all the universes!
I bow to you, You who are armed with mace, sword and Saranga. O Lord
of the universe, please forcibly throw me down from this chariot, O
You who're the shelter of all creatures.

त्वया हतस्येह ममाद्य कृष्ण श्रेयः परस्मिन्निह चैव लोके ।
संभावितोऽस्म्यन्धकवृष्णिनाथ लोकैस्त्रिभिर्वीर तवाभियानात् ॥ ९५ ॥


If I were to be slain here by You, great will be my fortune both in
this world and the next. You'd show me exalted regard, O Lord of the
Vrishnis and the Andhakas. My fame will be celebrated in all the three
worlds.”

रथादवप्लुत्य ततस्त्वरावान्पार्थोऽप्यनुद्रुत्य यदुप्रवीरम् ।
जग्राह पीनोत्तमलम्बबाहुं बाह्वोर्हरिं व्यायतपीनबाहुः ॥ ९६ ॥


Then Arjuna jumped down from his chariot and hurriedly chased after
the hero of the Yadus and seizes Him by his two hands.

निगृह्यमाणश्च तदादिदेवो भृशं सरोषः किल नाम योगी ।
आदाय वेगेन जगाम विष्णुर्जिष्णुं महावात इवैकवृक्षम् ॥ ९७ ॥


That incensed Supreme Being, though seized by Arjuna, forcibly drags
Jishnu after him, like a mighty wind which blows away a single tree.

पार्थस्तु विष्टभ्य बलेन पादौ भीष्मान्तिकं तूर्णमभिद्रवन्तम् ।
बलान्निजग्राह किरीटमाली पदेऽथ राजन्दशमे कथंचित् ॥ ९८ ॥


The high-souled Arjuna forcefully holds Krishna’s feet, as He rushed
towards Bhishma, and succeeded, in stopping Him with great difficulty
at the tenth step.

अवस्थितं च प्रणिपत्य कृष्णं प्रीतोऽर्जुनः काञ्चनचित्रमाली ।
उवाच कोपं प्रतिसंहरेति गतिर्भवान्केशव पाण्डवानाम् ॥ ९९ ॥


And when Krishna who was bedecked with a beautiful golden garland halted, Arjuna
bowed down to Him and said, “Subdue Your anger, O refuge of the
Pandavas,

न हास्यते कर्म यथाप्रतिज्ञं पुत्रैः शपे केशव सोदरैश्च ।
अन्तं करिष्यामि यथा कुरूणां त्वयाहमिन्द्रानुज संप्रयुक्तः ॥ १०० ॥


I swear by my sons and my brothers that I will not retreat from what I
have pledged myself to. Krishna, at Your command I will annihilate the
Kauravas.”

ततः प्रतिज्ञां समयं च तस्मै जनार्दनः प्रीतमना निशम्य ।
स्थितः प्रिये कौरवसत्तमस्य रथं सचक्रः पुनरारुरोह ॥ १०१ ॥


Hearing Arjuna’s vow, the Supreme Lord Janardana was pleased. And
devoted to the cause of that most excellent Kuru, He once again mounted
his chariot, still armed with His chakra.

स तानभीषून्पुनराददानः प्रगृह्य शङ्खं द्विषतां निहन्ता ।
विनादयामास ततो दिशश्च स पाञ्चजन्यस्य रवेण शौरिः ॥ १०२ ॥


And the Lord taking up the abandoned reins, and blowing on His conch
the Panchajanya, fills the earth and sky with its roaring sound.

व्याविद्धनिष्काङ्गदकुण्डलं तं रजोविकीर्णाञ्चितपक्ष्मनेत्रम् ।
विशुद्धदंष्ट्रं प्रगृहीतशङ्खं विचुक्रुशुः प्रेक्ष्य कुरुप्रवीराः ॥ १०३ ॥


Seeing Krishna, who was decked with necklaces, angada (arm-bands) and
earrings, His curling eyelashes coated with dust, His teeth of perfect
whiteness holding His conch once again, the Kuru heroes cry out
stridently.

मृदङ्गभेरीपटहप्रणादा नेमिस्वना दुन्दुभिनिस्वनाश्च ।
ससिंहनादाश्च बभूवुरुग्राः सर्वेष्वनीकेषु ततः कुरूणाम् ॥ १०४ ॥


The clash of cymbals and drums, and the thunder of chariot wheels and
the clatter of smaller drums, mingling with shouts of the Kurus caused
a fierce uproar.


So it is a cinematic creation ( but well made) not really in the Bhishma Parva as I had doubted. Thanks for the detailed response

You're welcome. There's another version of the Mahabharata which is also widely accepted and it's the Jaimini-Bharata. Might be worth checking there as well.

Please consult there also.

Looks like it's lost and some efforts were made to recover it. https://pradipbhattacharya.com/2017/10/09/the-lost-mahabharata-of-jaimini/.  The one available online appears to be a Kannada poem which is inspired by the original. Kindly accept the answer if you found it useful.
